# JDBC DriverManager can't access class in a different package

Tags: java, jdbc, bytecode, javaagents

I have been trying to instrument getconnection method to obtain the DB_URL passed during the connection establishment of JDBC. As far as i can understood, instrumentation of the DriverManager works fine because injecting part works fine without throwing any exceptions. But when it comes to executing that line, in my case calling a public static void method of a class in a package defined by me, it says

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: testInjection/TestClass
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:206)
    at testInstrumentation.TestConnector.main(TestConnector.java:30)
```

But same injection works fine for other classes. Little help would be really appreciated.

This is what i am injecting during instrumentation.

```
method.insertAt(1, true, "testInjection.TestClass.setConnetionURL($1);");
```

Answer (score 1):

You added a method call to the `java.sql.DriverManager` class that is loaded by the system class loader. The bootstrap class loader cannot see any classes that are loaded by the system class loader of which it is a parent.

To resolve this problem, you need to add your `testInjection.TestClass` to the bootstrap class loader. You can do this by setting a command line value `-Xbootclasspath` referencing a jar file with this class or programmatically by using the `Instrumentation` instance of your agent.